# Riddle: when do 10 Kohanim equal 1 Yisrael?

Tags: riddle, kohen-priest

Pretty much what the title says. Where in the Torah do we find something for which we need 10 Kohanim or 1 Yisrael?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a minyan with 11 Jews, if they are all Kohanim, one goes up to duchan and 10 stay behind and answer Amen.  If one of them is a Yisrael, all the Kohanim can duchan and the one Yisrael answers Amen (he is significant on his own since the main mitzva is to bless the Yisraelim. (SA OC 128:2,5 MB 101)

Comment: re your comment in the deleted answer below: If you don't mind my asking, what other meyuchas families do you know of? To what extent can they prove their yichus?

Comment: My former rav's last name was "Rappaport" and he was not a Cohen. I won't comment on what people thought of his yichus, but I don't think their opinion would have changed if he were a Cohen :-?

Comment: @DanF I know of a Rabbi Cohen who is actually just a Levi not a Cohen because when his great-grandfather came to the UK and couldn't speak any English and had a piece of paper that said Cohen as that was the name of the person he was going to stay with, ended up being called Cohen instead of Shumacher!!!

Comment: @JoshuaPearl There are plenty of anomalies. One of the former presidents in my shul had a last name "Katz". He was Yisra'el. I also know a Kahana who is a Levi.